# How to access button that is inside of handlebars template using javascript and jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, templates, handlebars.js

Is it possible to access button element that is inside of handlebars template?
I was trying to do that in regular, old-fashion way, by using javaScript, but I guess that template is not in DOM so I am always getting null when I try to find button on a page.

This is the code that represent handlebars template:

```
<script id="modal-template" type="text/x-handlebars-template">
    <div id="modalAddNewTest" class="modal">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <span class="close">x</span>
            <form name="formTestInfo" method="post">
                {{lblName}}<br>
                <input type="text" id="tbName" name="tbName">
                <p id="nameVal" class="text-color"></p>
                <br>
                {{lblTest}}<br>
                <div id="select-boxes">
                    <select class="dynamic-select" id="ddlTest">
                        <option value=""></option>
                        <option value="Belbin">Belbin</option>
                        <option value="Raven">Raven</option>
                        <option value="PPA">PPA</option>
                        <option value="PPA+">PPA+</option>
                        <option value="Basic Knowledge">Basic Knowledge</option>
                        <option value="PCT">PCT</option>
                    </select>
                </div>
                <p class="text-color" id="testVal"></p>
                <div id="newTest">
                </div>
                <br>
                <br>
                <button id="btnCancel" type="button">Cancel</button>
                <button id="btnSave" type="button">Save</button>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</script>
```

So as you can see there are two buttons inside of it:

```
<button id="btnCancel" type="button">Cancel</button>
<button id="btnSave" type="button">Save</button>
```

When I try to do this in javaScript:

```
//Remove modal on Cancel button
var btnCancel = document.getElementById("btnCancel");
btnCancel.onclick = function () {
  var container = $("div#modal");
  container.remove();
};
```

I get this exception:

[image]

Button is not recognized at all. 
Does someone know what is the best way to access the elements who are inside of Handlebars template?

Comment: You need to put that whole `onlick` assignment in a `document.onload` function so that the `getElementById` only executes after all of the scripts have complete.

Comment: Did you tried this method `$('#modal-template').on('click', '.btnCancel', function () {
 alert('clicked');
});` ?

Comment: How do you add the interpolated template to the DOM?